# create a column based on one other Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I would like to create a column called "target" which contains 0 value if name columns is "NaN" and 1 if it is non.

I did, like this:

```
df_opportunity['target'] = np.where(df_opportunity['name']=='NaN', '0', '1')
```

But it puts always 0

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please attach  a sample dataset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always found tricky the way to compare `NaN` in `pandas`. The appropriate would be:

```
df_opportunity['target'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df_opportunity['name']), '0', '1')
```